# What python can tell me about an object using just its own label?

Tags: python, debugging

```
def dummyFunction(context, data):
    ...
    doing something
    ...
    return something
```

I have a script that runs just fine but i would like to trace just 1-2 specific variables, for example supposing that i want to trace back all the changes and the history and the statements related to `data`, what python can do for me?

There is a built-in function in python that can help me to explode all the steps taken that are involving a particular variable? What i can discover in python knowing only the name of a variable?

To be really pedantic i would like to know all the possible informations about this label, but the reall really important ones are:

- what is the content of this variable and how and if it has changed during the execution
- where is declared

Comment: You can't declare variables in Python, so the second thing you're looking for is a non-starter.

Comment: @Wooble if i say that i'm looking for "the first time that they appear in the code" ?

Comment: use pdb (inside of eclipse its really easy...) and add a watch to that variable name and it will show you every time it changes value

Comment: @JoranBeasley can you show some good pdb command? my Python interpreter is customized but i have a command line access to the pdb module

Comment: some example http://www.cs.carleton.edu/faculty/dmusican/cs201w08/debuglab.pdf

Comment: what kind of customization does your interpreter have?

Comment: @JoranBeasley it's the Blender Python interpreter, custom modules and utils, and the executable and the libraries are bundled with the Blender package. By the way pdb is just an overkill, i need to just watch 1 label.

Comment: `pdb` works fine in Blender 2.5+ (Python 3.x), I'm using it all the time. And it's not overkill, it can be the scalpel in your toolkit if you set breakpoints in the right places and know how to move around the call stack.

Comment: @LukasGraf can you show how to use it in a script file for just 1 label ?

Comment: Sure, I'm currently writing an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Part of what you're asking (*how and if it has changed during the execution*) can only be answered by a back-in-time debugger. As far as I know some do exist, but overall that's more of a area of current research, and a massively complex problem to tackle. There's an interesting [Google Tech Talk about back in time debugging](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xpI8hIgOyko). But I wouldn't know of one being readily available for Python.

The good news is, you rarely ever need one.

For your example, I would approach debugging like this:

Set a breakpoint in the the first line of that function definition:

```
def dummyFunction(context, data):
    import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
```

This will kick you into pdb the first time that function is called (and on all the following calls).

Verify this by typing `l` (lowercase L), which lists the line of code you're currently at and some context around it.

Then, type `data` to inspect the contents of `data`. You can access and inspect objects like you would in the regular interactive interpreter.

Now, type `w` to see the call stack. The call you're currently in (`dummyFunction`) is at the bottom, the one that called it is at the second to last line.

Now you want to know *how* `data` became what it currently is. So you can move up and down the call stack, to why that function was called with that argument.

Type `u` to move up once in the call stack. You'll now be in the function that called `dummyFunction(context, data)`, and you'll be able to inspect the variables in the local scope of *that* function. So type `l` again to show the code, and study what happens a few lines before the call. Any conditions? What expressions do they depend on? Evaluate those expressions and inspect local variables (try `locals()`) to find out why your function was called with that argument. Check what arguments the calling function got.

Move up (`u`) or down (`d`) the stack as you need to. This doesn't move the instruction pointer at all, you're just peeling layers of the onion that represents your call stack.

At some point you'll know that something you care about happens at some particular line of code, but you're already past it (it's already been executed). Once you're confident that's the lead you want to follow, quit the current `pdb` session (`q`), remove your breakpoint and set a new one strategically placed before the interesting line of code.

Repeat until you find out what you want to know.

If any of your functions happen to be called hundreds of times, but you're only interested in a particular case, modify the code so the breakpoint will only be triggered when the conditions are met. For example:

```
if 'interesting' in data.keys():
    import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
```

Following this pattern will take you a *long* way to understanding and debugging your or other people's code. And remember: It's just Python ;-)

Answer (score 1):

For getting information about the content of a variable, you can use the dir(obj) function.

As in here:

```
class B(object):
    a = 0
    b = 1

b = B()
dir(b)
```

it will give you

```
['__class__',
 '__delattr__',
 '__dict__',
 '__doc__',
 '__format__',
 '__getattribute__',
 '__hash__',
'__init__',
 '__module__',
 '__new__',
 '__reduce__',
 '__reduce_ex__',
 '__repr__',
 '__setattr__',
 '__sizeof__',
 '__str__',
 '__subclasshook__',
 '__weakref__',
 'a',
 'b']
```

The inspect module, located inside the standard library, also have a lot of great tools to gather info about objects.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are better off if you write unit tests for your code (if you are not already doing so) and instead of passing real objects you pass mock objects using for example the [Mock](http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/mock/) library. You can then check if any calls to that object have been made.

Note that a variable name in Python is just a label, you better learn about pass-by-reference / pass-by-value etc. as this makes usually much more sense when debugging applications.

Comment: i know that i'm better learning Python in general, but i just getting started with Python and this is a custom Python interpreter, also i have no clue about how to debug in Python. I would like to not change the script because it's not just a function, i would like to study the overall behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to this post to learn more on how to use pdb in your code.  Python debugger is one of the best to achieve what you really want.

http://greeennotebook.com/2010/06/using-the-python-debugger-pdb/